# how can i toggle the color of the text inside a button

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle the color of the text inside a button after it's been clicked, currently the background color toggles on and off when clicking on a button,  but the text color of all buttons change at same time, i'd only like the selected button to change, how do i fix this ?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.newsbutton', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
$(document).on('click', '.newsbutton', '.btn-2', function() {
  $('.btn-2').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #56CCF2;
}

.active {
  background-color: #242424 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">
            <p href="" class="btn-2">BBC</p> 
            </button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">
            <p class="btn-2">The Guardian</p> 
            </button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">
            <p class="btn-2">Financial Times</p> 
            </button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">
            <p class="btn-2">Metro</p> 
            </button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">
            <p class="btn-2">Techcrunch</p> 
            </button>
```

Comment: i've changed the text to 'span' but the problem is the onclick function which alters all buttons,  I only want the selected button to toggle on/off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You cannot have `p` inside `button`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) Buttons can only have [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content). Use `span`s instead.

That being said, you are explicitly telling jQuery

```
$('.btn-2').addClass('selected');
```

to add that class to **all elements matching `.btn-2`**. Instead, use `this` and `find`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.newsbutton', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active').find('.btn-2').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #56CCF2;
}

.active {
  background-color: #242424 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton"><span class="btn-2">BBC</span></button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton"><span class="btn-2">The Guardian</span></button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton"><span class="btn-2">Financial Times</span></button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton"><span class="btn-2">Metro</span></button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton"><span class="btn-2">Techcrunch</span></button>
```

Comment: perfect , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.newsbutton', function() {
  $( ".btn-container .btn" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #56CCF2;
}

.active {
  background-color: #242424 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-container">
<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">BBC</button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">The Guardian
            </button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary newsbutton">Financial Times
            </button>
            </div>
```

I hope this what you looking for and BTW note don't use p tag inside button. If you needed use span tag

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly capturing the currently clicked button, but your issue is with how you are implementing the color change. I believe relying too much on JS here rather than on CSS over complicates things.

Note on my implementation I am only using `active` as the class which represents both the text color and background color change within the button itself. I am relying more on CSS to handle the style changes and letting JS toggle a single class `active`.

This simplification is reflected in the HTML due to removing the `span` dependency, since we are working directly on the `button`. Using a simple selector for listening to the click events "button" (or a class name if you feel more comfortable) and toggling a single class within the button itself. That reduces the complexity out of JS into CSS and as a result you get a cleaner HTML implementation.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
  color: black;
}
button.active {
  background-color: green !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">BBC</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">The Guardian</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">Financial Times</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">Metro</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">Techcrunch</button>
```